# How to extract GAE quota/dashboard data?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api

I would like to centralize my app's performance monitoring, so I should extract somehow GAE dashboard or quota usage details data. Is there any way to do it (for ex. with Google API)?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is an API provided by Google to get your quota statistics for App Engine application.

This is an Open Issue : https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=655 and you can get some hints from the thread about what other developers have been trying.

Answer (score 0):

Still waiting on official version.

Khan academy uses curl:
https://github.com/Khan/analytics/tree/master/src/gae_dashboard

Probably against terms of service, but I use mechanize to access the GAE dashboard (verified works from deployed app).

```
            import gaemechanize2._mechanize as mechanize
            self.br = mechanize.Browser()
            #self.br.set_all_readonly(False)    # allow everything to be written to
            self.br.set_handle_robots(False)   # ignore robots
            self.br.set_handle_refresh(False)  # can sometimes hang without this
            self.br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]
            self.br.open(given_source)
            loginForm = self.br.forms().next()
            loginForm["Email"] = self.the_email
            loginForm["Passwd"] = self.the_password
            response = self.br.open(loginForm.click())
            self.the_response=response.read()

            if re.search('Verify that it.*you',self.the_response):
                logging.info("BREAK: NOT YOU...trying again")
                loginForm=self.br.forms().next()
                loginForm.set_value(['PhoneVerificationChallenge'],name='challengetype')
                loginForm['phoneNumber']=self.the_phone
                response1=loginForm.click()
                response=self.br.open(response1)
                self.the_response=response.read()
```